# Performance problems with TOP and user defined functions in views

Tags: sql-server, performance, view, functions, nhibernate, query-performance

I have problem with performance of queries on simple query on view.

To keep things simple, assume my view is defined as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [mon].[ViewDevicesWithGroups]
AS
SELECT     Id, Name, Deleted, mon.SlowFunction(Id) AS Groups,
FROM         mon.Devices
```

And query I'm trying to optimize looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
Id218_0_, Groups, Name218_0_, DeletedD6_218_0_ FROM (
    SELECT this_.Id as Id218_0_, this_.Name as Name218_0_, this_.Deleted as Deleted218_0_, Groups, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY this_.Name) as __hibernate_sort_row
    FROM mon.ViewDevicesWithGroups this_
    WHERE (this_.Deleted = 1 and not (1=0))) AS query
WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > 100000
ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

My problem is, SQL server keeps executing this query in REALLY wrong order - SlowFunction is really slow, and should be delayed as long as possible:
[image: slow query]

As you can see, this query was generated by ORM (NHibernate in this case), and I can't change it directly (otherwise this problem would be trivial to solve by just moving function call to outermost select).

Can performance of my query be improved without changes in application code (maybe I kind of hint on view/function)? Because that query is abstracted deeply inside DAL in my application, and changing it would require A LOT of work.

Comment: What is `SlowFunction()`? Do you really need to run SlowFunction for every single row?

Comment: No, thats the problem - I only need to know SlowFunction value for selected rows (in my use case, ony top 10 rows). But SQL server insists on evaluating it before TOP and filtering.

Comment: So stop using the view and apply SlowFunction() on the outer part of your query.

Comment: Check articles about plan guides, for instance  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417(v=sql.100).aspx . However, it appears to me that you're trying to solve ORM problems on SQLServer side.  It's not gonna work in a long term even if you find a hack for this very specific issue.

Comment: @MSM what version of SQL server are you running?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 locally, but production runs on SQL Server 2010

Comment: @MSM enterprise or standard edition?  Can the result from SlowFunction be stored or does each row need to be evaluated at execution time?

Comment: @MSM do you mean [Sql Server 2008R2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), or [Search Server 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd183108%28v=Office.14%29.aspx)?  I'm not familiar with SQL Server 2010.

Comment: Duh, sorry. I confused Visual Studio edition with SQL server version. I meant sql server 2008 R2 of course.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call a stored procedure via NHibernate instead of asking it to query the view?  That would allow you to write your own query and tune as needed....

I don't know NHibernate very well but [this blog post](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/09/27/nhibernate-and-stored-procedures-in-c/) looks like a reasonable resource.  In case that link dies here are the basic steps:

1. Write your stored procedure to select the data in the most efficient manner.
2. Write a class that represents the data you're selecting (a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) would be perfect).
3. Write a NHibernate mapping that tells it how to associate the fields
4. Specify the name of the stored procedure to use and any parameters when you query the database via NHibernate.

It might be a good idea to check out [this article on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103/what-is-the-best-way-to-improve-performance-of-nhibernate) related to tuning performance when using NHibernate.